# Looking for fee free services to transfer small amounts of money between accounts owned by the same person

Tags: api, online-payment, web-apis

I'm looking for services with API's that will do fee free transfers of money between bank accounts, these accounts will both be controlled by the same person, but may not be under the same bank.  Each transfer will be small, most less than $5, but some may go higher, there really is no upper bound on the use case.  I may be able to batch these transfers for services with fees, if the fee is small enough, but that is less than ideal for my use case.

I know Paypal can do this with a fairly significant delay (10-14 days), but I am looking for all viable options here.  I would like to support as many services as possible.

### Edit - Additional details

I am a developer exploring the feasibility of creating an application to assist users in adopting good savings habits.  To do this I need them to be able to make the decision, hopefully several times a day, to fore-go an impulse buy, and instead transfer that money from their transactional account, to a savings type account.

So I need to support as many user's account set ups as possible, while ideally supporting the least number of API's.  Fee's must be as close to 0 as possible as the purpose of the app is to save as much money as possible.

Comment: Please do state what country you need this to work in. Online Payment differs significantly throughout the world. Also, please note that your bank(s) may have such api already in place and most likely you can tap into this.

Comment: True, and good point.  US is the initial target market, but expanding to other countries is certainly on the road map assuming there are services out there that can support me.

Comment: As far as bank-supplied services go, aren't they only valid when both accounts are in the same bank?  I'll have to do some research to see how standardized their API's are.

Comment: So, do you want to connect to the banks themselves (using a library and writing the code yourself) or do you want to use a third party service API? (if so, why not use a library?) I recommend you tell us what problem you want to solve so the money experts can figure out what to use best.

Comment: At least in Europe I have a connection to my bank that I can program on. And it contains actions like "transfer that amount of money to that bankaccount of this bank". My bank has a fee on this but the same goes for all other transfers as well. But european Banks work different to US ones (and I don't know US ones)

Answer (score 3):

[Dwolla.com](https://www.dwolla.com/)

1. Free for transactions $10 or less
2. Only for US financial institutions
3. $0.25 fee for transactions over $10
4. [API available](https://www.dwolla.com/developers)